# Where is the jumper to reset BIOS on Toshiba Satellite P855

Tags: bios, toshiba-laptop

I have done a lot of research on this. I have disassembled the laptop, removed the ram, but do not know which jumper to short. Survey says I'm looking for "b500" or "xxx".

Does anyone know which jumper to short to reset BIOS password on Toshiba Satellite P855 series?

Here is what it looks like when the memory is removed:

[image]

Should I attempt to short those two solder points on the middle left side?

EDIT

I believe it says password reset is JPW. I have tried jumping JPW and JCMOS as shown in the image. No dice on password reset.

Comment: Where exactly have you looked? For many Toshiba laptops it is under the memory. For the C850, the jumper is B500. Likely the same for P850.

Comment: I have checked under the memory for sure. There is no B500. I will upload an image when I get back to work.

Comment: I have added a picture for reference

Comment: I removed the link you added because it had an invalid path to your `C:\` drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jumper to reset the bios password on the toshiba p855 is labeled JPW. It's right next to the RAM slots. Easy to spot.

Just remove the casing protecting the battery + RAM + HDD + WIFI card, remove both ram sticks. Put one ram stick back into the top most slot. RAM is needed for the PC to run. I tried different combinations of shorting both the JCMOS and JPW jumpers, entering the bios [ which is allowed once after shorting the JCMOS with no hard drive plugged in ] , and removing the HDD.

I was using screwdivers with no success. I ended up using some copper wire and the above combos and eventually tricked into working.

If anyone else is having trouble with this leave a comment if more information or pictures are needed

Answer (score 2):

The `JCMOS` is the jumper you are looking for.

[image]

[Reference 1](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2241396/cmos-reset-motherboard.html)

[Reference 2](http://digitalbart.com/blog/toshiba-satellite-a665-s5170-bios-password.html)

Comment: Awesome! So that's just the two bronzish coloured pins just above the lettering?

Comment: Yes. Just to the left of the `S` in the picture above. Use a flat blade screw driver or tip of a key to make a connection for a few seconds.

Comment: Will try this out and accept. Thank you so much.

Comment: Doing this with no hard drive as provided in reference 2 allows me to enter bios. Awesome! There is a supervisor password set. If I try and edit it I need the current password. No good. Any advice?

Comment: Is there a BIOS battery next to the hard drive compartment?

Comment: There is a bios soldered to the motherboard on the front left. Should I attempt to remove and resolder?

Comment: I was asking about a bios battery, not a chip, because there might be a chance the reset jumper is next to it.

Comment: I'm pretty positive that it's the bios battery. It's unlike a desktop bios battery, it's blue and soldered in. Looks like this http://www.laptopparts101.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/cmos-battery-soldered-560x420.jpg

Comment: OK. That is what I was asking. From what I have found, the B500 or XXX jumper might be in the proximity of that battery. If so, reinstall the memory, leave the HDD out, short the jumper and power on holding the jumper in place until the Toshiba logo goes away on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have the P855 model and I found on my laptop, JWP.
[JPW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBNEv.jpg) 
So all I have to do is tough these two copper circles together?
I tried with a paper clip and a screw driver and it didn't work.
No sure if there are more steps I needed.
initially I took out battery, 1 RAM card + HDD + WIFI card as mentioned above.
Do I need to hold down the power button for a long time?
Will anything appear on screen once the power button is pressed?
I still ended up seeing a black screen once I pressed the power button once.

With no visual,  I connected the RAM + HDD + WIFI card back with no luck.
[JWP2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9EQY.jpg)

Comment: Gabriel, you have posted a comment where there are supposed to be answers. Interact with the SuperUser a bit and build up the reputation necessary to comment. If your question isn't answered by other answers to this question, then ask a new question of your own by click the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

I own a Toshiba laptop satellite L670 and you just have to short the two copper pin close to the Jcmos for ten seconds then plug the power, press the start button and finally have it back to normal but the password is still needed.

Comment: Isn't this already mentioned in another answer?